# destroy a view when back button is pressed

Tags: iphone, uiview, back-button, pushviewcontroller

My navigation controller is organized this way:

FirstViewController -> SecondViewController -> ThirdViewController

in the First I do a search on the web and I display the result in a UITableView
when I select a cell I push to the Second where I do another search based on key previously pressed and I display some information and a button for "more info"
when I press the button I push to the Third view and this works fine...

The problem is when I press two times the back button for doing another search: when I arrive at the third view I display every time the informations about the first search!

this is because I do the display of information in loadView and this is called only the first time, right?

How should I do?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `viewDidShow` is called *after the view has been loaded and created from the NIB file*. This means you should only use that method to do initialization stuff.

Add a new method and call it everytime you have new results:

```
- (void) updateAndShowResults
{
    // Code to update third view goes here
    // and is always called whenever some new results are available
}
```

You'd call it from the first or second view controller like this:

```
[thirdView updateAndShowResults];
```

Hope that helps. Please mark the best answer by clicking the "√" on the left! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can clean up the the ThirdViewController in viewdidunload.

Comment: That makes no sense if you want to re-use the view for multiple searches.